# How can I create a pre-signed url to download a file from an AWS-s3 Bucket for 36 hours in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sts

My aws-lambda code right now is:

```
    'use strict';
    
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    
    class AwsS3Repository {
      constructor() {
        this.s3 = new AWS.S3();
      }
    
      async getSignedUrl ({ bucketName, Key, Expires }) {
        const params = { 
          Bucket: "bucket_name", 
          Key: "key_name",
          Expires: 60 * 60 * 36,
        }
    
        return this.s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
      }
    } 
    
    module.exports = AwsS3Repository;
```

While it's working, the expiration time is ignoring the parameter "expires" and instead is expiring in what seems to be less than one hour.

I've read in the [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/) that you need to use STS to create links that will be valid to 36 hours, so I've created an STS with trusted policy to my lambda function in AWS, so I'm able to use STS.assume as you can see in this example:

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    // Set the region 
    AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});
    
    var roleToAssume = {RoleArn: 'my_role',
                        RoleSessionName: 'session1',
                        DurationSeconds: 900,};
    var roleCreds;
    
    // Create the STS service object    
    var sts = new AWS.STS({apiVersion: '2011-06-15'});
    
    //Assume Role
    sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else{
            roleCreds = {accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                         secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                         sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken};
            stsGetCallerIdentity(roleCreds);
        }
    });
    
    //Get Arn of current identity
    function stsGetCallerIdentity(creds) {
        var stsParams = {credentials: creds };
        // Create STS service object
        var sts = new AWS.STS(stsParams);
            
        sts.getCallerIdentity({}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.Arn);
            }
        });    
    }
```

However, I still don't understand how I will use STS to create the pre-signed url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating an IAM role that has permission to create signed url in my S3 bucket and setting it to trust my lambda through the trust policy option in AWS, then updating the AWS-SDK config to use the IAM credentials returned by the sts.assumeRole method.

```
    async assumeRole() {
    const roleToAssume = {
      RoleArn: 'my-sts-role-in-aws',
      RoleSessionName: 'session1',
      DurationSeconds: 900,
    };

    const sts = new AWS.STS({ apiVersion: '2011-06-15' });

    const roleCreds = await sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume).promise()

    AWS.config.update({ 
      accessKeyId: roleCreds.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: roleCreds.secretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: roleCreds.sessionToken,
      region: 'us-east-1',
      signatureVersion: 'v4'
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "permission to create [a] signed url". Anyone, regardless of permissions, can *create* a signed URL. What's important is that the credentials used to sign the URL actually have permission to access the AWS resource associated with the signed URL, that those credentials are still active at the time the signed URL is used to access the resource, and that the signed URL has not yet expired.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs for [getSignedUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property), you will see that expiration is specified in seconds, not in hours:

> Expires (Integer) — default: 900 — the number of seconds to expire the pre-signed URL operation in. Defaults to 15 minutes.

Comment: The question _is_ assuming seconds for the `Expires: 60 * 60 * 36` is 36 hours in seconds.

Comment: @icc97 yes, but that's because the OP modified the posted code *after* I supplied this answer, to read `60 * 60 * 36` when it was originally `60 * 36`.